# Access all tasks for each user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a restful api and I am using this tutorial as a guide: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/

In the example there is a tasks table, a user table and a users tasks table.  For my application I want to have it so that each user can access all tasks. I can do this if I go to phpmyadmin and manually set each user to each and every task. This is very laborious though. If I had many users this would not be practical at all. Is there a way to assign each individual user to every task automatically? For example some kind of macro?

Comment: your question isn't clear, explain it more

Comment: Can you show table name with there column names?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you do not need the middleman, aka user_tasks table, so just leave it out of your query:

```
   public function getAllUserTasks($user_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM tasks t");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $tasks = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
    return $tasks;
}
```